# Formset save and update

Tags: django

I have an inlineformset which displays a maximum of 10 forms. But when I try to save/update the formset these extra objects ( which are blank in content ) also get saved. So everytime the formset is saved/edited these blank records keep entering into the database. What could the reason be ?

Comment: The problem is on line 10.

Seriously, if you want us to help, you'll need to post some code.

Answer (score 9):

In your view when you get a POST with a formset you have to check each form to make sure it has changed (this way empties will get disregarded). I also include an additional check for deleted forms if you have delete enabled:

```
for form in formset.forms:
  if form.has_changed():
       if not form in formset.deleted_forms:
            # Do something with this form
```

Comment: great , i got rid of the duplication problem due to deletes but not the update/duplication problem thanks anyway